# Turan-related graph theory question

Tags: graph-theory

Let us have a $G$ graph, which has $4$ vertices and $4$ edges, and $3$ vertices create a triangle. What is the value of $ex(n,G)$ for all $n$?

So basically the task is: If I have $n$ vertices, what is the maximum value of edges I can draw within that graph, that it doesn't conntain our $G$ graph as sub-graph. My first idea was that I can just draw disjunct triangles, in this case, for $n$ vertices I have $n$ edges. This does not contain $G$ as subgraph, but I am not sure that the number of edges is maximal.

Does Turan theorem helps me somehow, or what is the main idea of solving this task? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) is indeed what you need, because the best way to avoid a subgraph isomorphic to $G$ is to produce a [triangle-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph) graph.

According to the special case of Turán's theorem called Mantel's theorem, the maximum number of edges in an n-vertex triangle-free graph is $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor$, achieved by creating a complete bipartite graph with the parts as nearly equal as possible. The girth of complete bipartite graphs is of course $4$.

42 edges using 13 vertices, $K_{7,6}$:

[image]